# Confused over access to private variable from Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a bit confused over why I have access to a private variable from a linq query?

The access is in the PropertyName method and accessing the _propertyName variable.  I thought since it was private I wouldn't have access to it?

```
public class ObjectGraph
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get
        {
            // ermmm, not sure why this Select can access _propertyName???
            var parents = string.Join("/", Parents.Select(p => p._propertyName));
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}", parents, _propertyName);
        }
    }

    public ObjectReplicationContext Source { get; private set; }

    public int ClosestParentId { get; set; }

    public bool TraverseChildren { get; set; }

    public List<ObjectGraph> Parents { get; set; }

    public ObjectGraph(object source, string propertyName)
    {
        Source = new ObjectReplicationContext(source);
        _propertyName = propertyName;

        Parents = new List<ObjectGraph>();
        TraverseChildren = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot directly access anything marked as private externally, but indirectly you can, such as in your example.  If this weren't the case, private variables would have no use.

Comment: @Khan - there is no "external" access in the sample - as Andy(+1) answer shows lambda converted into anonymous private method in the *same class* - it can directly access any private fields/methods/properties. Note that if local variables would be involved instead of methods there will be nested class generated, but again it will have [direct access to private fields of its outer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx). You can check [Lambda ...](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/FreeBookArticles/AddisonWesley/2009Oct13001134AM/DelegatesLambda/7.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can always access its own private members.  The lambda is just an anonymous callback method that exists within the class; it syntactic sugar provided by the C# compiler.

Imagine you had this instead

```
private static string GetProperyName(ObjectGraph obj) {
  return obj._propertyName;
}

public string PropertyName
{
   get
   {
        // ermmm, not sure why this Select can access _propertyName???
        var parents = string.Join("/", Parents.Select(GetProperyName));
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}", parents, _propertyName);
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to your code.